# SVN - How to make an older revision the head revision?

Tags: svn

One of the files in my current head revision got corrupted. I want to make an older revision of that file the head revision as usually people sync to head revsion in my project. How to do that?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You should revert all changes since that old reversion. In principle,

```
svn merge -rHEAD:oldrev filename
svn commit -m "rolled back to oldrev"
```

should do. The later revisions are still there, but reverted.

Answer (score 12):

You should do a [reverse merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.branchmerge.commonuses.html#svn.branchmerge.commonuses.undo).