# svn fix something in an old revision for all newer revisions

Tags: svn

I've created a fix on lets say revision 100, that broke something important.
But now we have 15 more revisions, a couple used in production envs.

What I want is to create a revision 100a, fix the issue that was created in rev 100 and then also make it available for 101 to 115. Is this posible at all?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change history. However, you can undo the change made at revision 100, creating revision 116.

See this [related discussion on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271380/svn-how-to-make-an-older-revision-the-head-revision?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks. I could create a branch for revision 100. Fix it in version 116 within the branch and merge it into the main into version 117, right?

Comment: I don't see how creating a branch would be advantageous here. Check out the HEAD revision from where you normally work (trunk?), fix the bug, and commit it. Or check out HEAD, perform a reverse merge to undo the change made at revision 100 (see the link I gave), then make the correct change and commit that.

Comment: The thing is that (for instance) revision 101, 108 and 115 are used in the production env and that the fix in revision 100 is partly ok, so just undu of 100 is also not what I need. Is this possible?

Comment: Most people don't mix revisions in a release to begin with. If your bug in revision 100 is contained to specific files, and the *whole* change to each file in revision 100 is buggy, then you can reverse those individual files. But to me, it would make for a cleaner release/change history to reverse the entire buggy commit, then commit a fix as a new revision. Or simply fix the bug in the `HEAD` revision and release that (and perform no reversals).